# To convert a byte array to String in robotframework

Tags: java, robotframework

For robotframework I need to write a code which can convert a byte array to a String. But before that, do I need to know about the size of the byte array?

I tried this one:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static byte[] retrievePolicy(String aPolicyNumber) {

        String METHOD_NAME="retrievePolicy";
        byte[] myBinData = null;
        Connection myConnection = null;
        String mySelectSql = "SELECT PSD_BIN_DATA FROM XAT_POLICY_STUB_DATA WHERE PSD_POLICY_NBR = ?";
        String myWorkingQuerySelect;
        
        //Statement myStmt = null;
        PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
        String myJndiName;

        try {
            DataSource myDataSource;
            myJndiName = AllcorpProperties.getProperty(ALLIANCE_STUB_DATASOURCE_JNDI_NAME);
            myWorkingQuerySelect= mySelectSql;

            myDataSource = ServiceLocator.obtainDataSource(myJndiName);
            if(myDataSource!=null) {
                myConnection = myDataSource.getConnection();
                if(myConnection != null){
                    //myStmt = myConnection.createStatement();
                    myPreparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(myWorkingQuerySelect);
                    myPreparedStatement.setString(1, aPolicyNumber);
                    ResultSet resultSet = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
                                
                    if (resultSet != null && resultSet.next()) {
                        Blob myBlob = resultSet.getBlob(1);
                        if (myBlob != null) {
                            myBinData = myBlob.getBytes((long) 1, (int) myBlob.length());
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    PolicyServiceException myPolicyServiceException = new PolicyServiceException(new AllcorpException(),
                            EXCEPTION_OBTAINING_CONNECTION,
                            PolicyDAO.CDB_COMMUNICATION_ERROR, METHOD_NAME,BUSINESS_FUNCTION_NAME);
                    AllcorpLogger.error(CLASS_NAME,myPolicyServiceException);
                    throw myPolicyServiceException;
                }
                
            }else{
                PolicyServiceException myPolicyServiceException = new PolicyServiceException(new AllcorpException(),
                        EXCEPTION_STATEMENT_GET_DATASOURCE,
                        PolicyDAO.CDB_COMMUNICATION_ERROR, METHOD_NAME,BUSINESS_FUNCTION_NAME);
                AllcorpLogger.error(CLASS_NAME,myPolicyServiceException);
                throw myPolicyServiceException;
                        }

        } catch (SQLException mySQLException) {

            AllcorpLogger.error(CLASS_NAME,new PolicyServiceException(mySQLException,
            "Error occurred while retreiving policy  from stub DB for policy number "+aPolicyNumber,"SDBURTP",METHOD_NAME,BUSINESS_FUNCTION_NAME));
        } catch(AllcorpInfrastructureException myAllcorpInfrastructureException)
        {
            PolicyServiceException myAllcorpException = new PolicyServiceException(
                    myAllcorpInfrastructureException, "Exception while obtaining the data source ",
                    "STUBDBRP", METHOD_NAME, BUSINESS_FUNCTION_NAME);
            AllcorpLogger.error(CLASS_NAME, myAllcorpException);
        }
        catch (Exception myException) {

            AllcorpLogger.error(CLASS_NAME,new PolicyServiceException(myException,
                    "Error occurred while retrieving policy from StubDB for policy number " +aPolicyNumber,"STUBDRP2",METHOD_NAME,BUSINESS_FUNCTION_NAME));
        }finally {
            try {
                if (myPreparedStatement != null) {
                    myPreparedStatement.close();
                }
                if(myConnection != null){
                myConnection.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException myException) {
                AllcorpLogger.error(CLASS_NAME,new PolicyServiceException(myException,
                        "Error closing prepared statement object","SDBURTP1",METHOD_NAME,BUSINESS_FUNCTION_NAME));
            }
        }
        return myBinData;
    }
```

Comment: the policy which i need is a (BLOB)

Comment: I'm a little confused. You posted a big chunk of code but I have no idea where in there your problem lies? Please clarify why you cannot use for example `new String(byte[] bytes)` or `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byte[] val)` and - if possible reduce the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your robot file

```
${temp} =    Convert To Bytes    0102030405    hex
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a byte[] you can convert it to String using
new String(byte[],charset), e.g.

```
byte[] b = ...; //However you got that byte[]
String charsetName = "UTF-8"; //Or whatever the charset was using for encoding
String result = new String(b,charsetName);
```

You have to know, in which charset the byte[] was encoded. Typical values are
"UTF-8" or "ISO-8859-1".